# Groovy list apply closure

Tags: list, groovy

Simple question. I'm to write a void "apply" which perform Closure on each element of the List.

```
class Lista {

  def applay(List l, Closure c){
    return l.each(c)
  }

  static main(args) {
    Lista t = new Lista()
    List i = [1,2,3,8,3,2,1]
    Closure c = {it++}
    println t.applay(i, c)
  }
}
```

Do You have any idea what is wrong with that?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that the closure `{it++}` increments every element in the List by 1, but the result is not saved anywhere. I guess what you want to do is create a new List that contains the result of applying this closure to each element of the orginal List. If so, you should use `collect` instead of `each`.

```
class Lista {

  def applay(List l, Closure c){
    return l.collect(c) // I changed this line
  }

  static main(args) {
    Lista t = new Lista()
    List i = [1,2,3,8,3,2,1]
    Closure c = {it + 1} // I changed this line
    println t.applay(i, c)
  }
}
```

Comment: @user1138470 Consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer, or at *least* upvoting--it's not just a warm fuzzy for Don, it also helps future visitors know that an answer helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Alternative answer (not so Java-like):

```
class Lista {
    def apply = { list, closure -> list.collect(closure) }

    def main = {
        println apply([1,2,3,8,3,2,1], {it + 1})
    }
}
```

​